# Trouble decoding utf-16 string

Tags: python, python-3.x, decode, utf

I'm using `python3.3`. I've been trying to decode a certain string that looks like this:

```
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xed:\xf9w\xdaH\xd2?\xcf\xbc....
```

keeps going on. However whenever I try to decode this string using `str.decode('utf-16')` I get an error saying:

```
'utf16' codec can't decode bytes in position 54-55: illegal UTF-16 surrogate
```

I'm not exactly sure how to decode this string.

Comment: So that means it isn't really UTF16. Where did you get the string? Might it be UCS2?

Comment: Does the result look ok, if you only decode up to position 53? This may help to decide whether your assumption `utf16` is correct.

Comment: I got it from Twisted,  I went in `twisted/web/proxy.py` in the `handleResponsePart(self, buffer)` function, I just injected `print(buffer)`. So basically the encoded string you're looking at is supposed to be HTML, that I receive from Twisted proxies

Comment: so the actual string is huge, what I pasted is only a small part of the full string.

Comment: Try explicitly decoding to `'UTF-16BE'` and `'UTF-16LE'` — endianess might be the issue.

Comment: Dang I've tried decode using UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE, and UTF-16, And It still showing the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gzipped data [begins with `\x1f\x8b\x08`](http://www.filesignatures.net/index.php?page=search&search=GZ&mode=EXT) so my guess is that your data is gzipped. Try [gunzipping the data](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/gzip.html) before decoding.

```
import io
import gzip

# this raises IOError because `buf` is incomplete. It may work if you supply the complete buf
buf = b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xed:\xf9w\xdaH\xd2?\xcf\xbc'
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=io.BytesIO(buf)) as f:
    content = f.read()
    print(content.decode('utf-16'))
```