# how to decode a byte into a string with python?

Tags: python, utf-8, byte, decode

MY CODE

```
import socket

BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
HOST = '192.168.1.3'
PORT = 5555        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(10)
    while 1:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            print('Connected by', addr[0] + ":" + str(addr[1]))
            msg = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

            print(msg.decode('UTF-8'))
```

and when I execute
**the code I get a print (msg.decode (encoding = 'UTF-8', errors = 'strict'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 6: invalid start byte**
you can help me

Comment: It seems that you are not receiving valid utf8 strings, maybe the content your trying to decode is gzipped ( [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659851/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x8b-in-position-1-invalid#44660123)), but its impossible to know without knowing what your expecting or seeing the raw data

Comment: You can try .decode('utf-8', errors='ignore') to see if anything can be decoded, and investigate what part of the text is giving you trouble.  Maybe you are not getting utf-8 and you need utf-16 or something else?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897662/trouble-decoding-utf-16-string

Comment: It's impossible to help you without seeing the actual content of `msg`.  The rest of the code is irrelevant.  The short answer is whatever you received isn't encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide `msg.decode (encoding = 'UTF-8', errors = 'backslashreplace')` in your [mcve]. (Share _sanitized_ data.)